# \part doesn't appear  in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I use the  `article` document class and I created a TOC. It works fine and uses the `\section` to write the header, but the problem is that the first page after my TOC is the introduction and there I used `\part` without any `\section`. This is not recognized and so on the introduction page in the header it says "Contents" and not "Introduction". Can anyone help?

```
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{Chapter1} 
%\newpage
\input{Chapter2}
```

etc.

and the chapters are like:

```
\part{Chapter1} 
\part{Chapter2} 
\section
\section
```

But the problem is, Chapter 1 has no `\section` and is not recognized.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your problem. First of all it puzzles me that you use the part structure (which you call chapter). Part uses roman numbering - are you sure you want that? The highest structure level in an article class (that is using latin numbers) is as far as I know the `section` and in any case, the syntax to use it is: `\section{This is the title of my section}`. This title then also appears in the toc.

Comment: @Philipp The standard `article` class *does* feature `\part` (here not followed by a page break).

Comment: I know, but I was just confused by the way it is used. 

Anyway, as far as I can grasp the problem the only problem I see is how the `section` command was used. Else I dont see why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Please, provide a *real* example of what you're doing. However, using `article` and `\part` to emulate chapters is quite strange: use the `book` class.

Answer (score 1):

If the answer is really that simple, I'll give it a shot:

To use the section command you need to pass an argument, namely the name of the section which looks like this:

```
\section{Introduction}
```

This line then creates an entry in the toc with the name Introduction and also creates a section within the document with this title.

Comment: well, thanks for your answers but it does not solve my problem, I want that \part and you said that article does feature it, so it should work, but it doesnt, the \part{Introduction} is not in the header which is created by the toc. You know what I mean? It is in the toc, but the header on the next page says "content" and not "Introduction".

Answer (score 1):

You must issue a `\mark` command to fill the header. Probably `\markright{Introduction}`.

Comment: That certainly works for the first page where the command is issued but am I right when I say it needs manually repeated if there are more than just one page (which could be a bit tedious if that part is a long one - but then again, since there occurs no section it rather unlikely to be that long)?

Comment: The effect of a \mark command doesn't end at a page break. Also remark that the question title speaks of the toc. But the text of the header.

Comment: hey Ulrike thanks a lot! it really worked! thanks!!

Comment: @useranflatex Please don't post comments as another answer. I converted your non-answer to a comment to Ulrike's answer. And if you like her answer, please consider upvoting and accepting it.